# memory monitoring of grails 3.1 application

Tags: performance, grails, grails-3.1

I am currently using grails 3.1.
Kindly share the details of any monitoring plugin like grails-melody which is used in grails 2.*.
To my knowledge, grails-melody plugin is not applicable in grails 3+ version.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

JavaMelody plugin works fabulously with Grails 3.1.

The source documentation is the most current, here:

```
https://github.com/javamelody/grails-melody-plugin
```

Just include this in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:grails-melody-plugin:1.60.1'
}
```

As of September 2016, the current version is 1.60.1.

Just build and run your project, then go to http://localhost:8080/monitoring to see your monitoring information.  Replace the http://localhost:8080 bit as per your configuration, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Since Grails 3 is build on Spring Boot, you get Actuator out of the box. See [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/grails-goodness-adding-health) for more info.